# JavaScript6: adding element (key, value) to a ES6 map

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, jsx

In jsx I have a map like:

```
var myMap=Map([['rowNumber', '30'], ['id', '80'], ['firstName', '180'], ['lastName', '180'], ['mobile', '180'], ['username', '180'], ['password', '180']])
```

how can I do programatically add new element like: ['ssn', '12']
to this map?

Comment: "grammatically"? Just insert them in the code?

Comment: like:  myMap.push(['ssn', '12'])?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `new Map(…)`?

Comment: The map already exist. I wanted to add another element using a kind of push  method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for the [`set` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/set):

```
myMap.set('ssn', '12');
```

If you have an entry tuple, you can use

```
const newEntry = ['ssn', '12'];
myMap.set(newEntry[0], newEntry[1]);
// or also
myMap.set(...newEntry) // however that might be confusing
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the Map reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map

You can add items to a map with: `myMap.set(keyString, "value associated with 'a string'");`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`set()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/set) method with spread syntax to add array of two elements as key and value.

```js
var myMap = new Map([['rowNumber', '30'], ['id', '80'], ['firstName', '180'], ['lastName', '180'], ['mobile', '180'], ['username', '180'], ['password', '180']])

myMap.set(...['ssn', '12'])
for(var i of myMap) console.log(i)
```